# How Do I Select a Button URL Based On The Combination of a Radio Button & a Checkbox Data?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I do this with Javascript?

==============

Here’s the setup I need:

**Radio Button** 
Button 1 
Button 2 (default) 
Button 3

**Checkbox** 
Unchecked (default) 
Checked

**Button** 
URL 1 : Button 1 + unchecked 
URL 2 : Button 2 + unchecked (default) 
URL 3 : Button 3 + unchecked 
URL 4 : Button 1 + checked 
URL 5 : Button 2 + checked 
URL 6 : Button 3 + checked

—————————

Here’s my humble attempt to setup above minus Javascript:

```html
<!-- Radio buttons_Button 2 selected by default -->
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> Radio 1<br>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" checked> Radio 2<br>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3"> Radio 3<br> 
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">
 <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio2 & Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1'><button>URL1 Radio1 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url2'><button>URL2 Radio2 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url3'><button>URL3 Radio3 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url4'><button>URL4 Radio1 & Checked</button></a>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url5'><button>URL5 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
 <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url6'><button>URL6 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to setup my website with my newbie skills. Struggling to connect the dots after taking online courses & tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question,

1. first make all links have **data-** annotation to know the radio value and checked status to show it
2. Add **Shared class name** to all links to dis-active it easily
3. Call the JavaScript function **on every change** on radio and checkbox
4. Call the JavaScript function **on load page**

each link or button add

< a **class="my-toggle-links"** href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1' **data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"** >URL1 Radio1 & Unchecked

and in JavaScript

```
var radioSelector = 'input[name="radio"]';
var checkboxSelector = 'input[name="checkbox"]';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(radioSelector  +', '+ checkboxSelector).change(setActiveLinks);
});

function setActiveLinks() {
   var radioValue = $(radioSelector +':checked').val();
   var isChecked = $(checkboxSelector).prop("checked");

   // first dis-active links
   $('.my-toggle-links > button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   // second active
   var activeSelector = '.my-toggle-links[data-radio="'+ radioValue +'"][data-checked="'+ isChecked +'"]';
   $(activeSelector + ', ' + activeSelector +' > button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Your code will be like this:

```
<!-- Radio buttons_Button 2 selected by default -->
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> Radio 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" checked> Radio 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3"> Radio 3<br> 
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio2 & Unchecked by default -->
<div>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="false"><button>URL1 Radio1 & Unchecked</button></a>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url2' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="false"><button>URL2 Radio2 & Unchecked</button></a>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url3' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="false"><button>URL3 Radio3 & Unchecked</button></a>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url4' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"><button>URL4 Radio1 & Checked</button></a>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url5' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="true"><button>URL5 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
    <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url6' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="true"><button>URL6 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
</div>
```

---

the Whole Code will be **HTML + JavaScript** :

```js
var radioSelector = 'input[name="radio"]';
var checkboxSelector = 'input[name="checkbox"]';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(radioSelector  +', '+ checkboxSelector).change(setActiveLinks);
   
   // call it on load
   setActiveLinks();
});

function setActiveLinks() {
   var radioValue = $(radioSelector +':checked').val();
   var isChecked = $(checkboxSelector).prop("checked");

   // first dis-active links
   $('.my-toggle-links > button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   // second active
   var activeSelector = '.my-toggle-links[data-radio="'+ radioValue +'"][data-checked="'+ isChecked +'"]';
   $(activeSelector + ', ' + activeSelector +' > button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

```html
<!-- Radio buttons_Button 2 selected by default -->
<div>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> Radio 1</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" checked> Radio 2</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3"> Radio 3</label><br> 
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">
 <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio2 & Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="false"><button>URL1 Radio1 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url2' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="false"><button>URL2 Radio2 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url3' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="false"><button>URL3 Radio3 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url4' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"><button>URL4 Radio1 & Checked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url5' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="true"><button>URL5 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url6' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="true"><button>URL6 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

***Updated 2:***

make the visible only one button

---

```js
var radioSelector = 'input[name="radio"]';
var checkboxSelector = 'input[name="checkbox"]';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(radioSelector  +', '+ checkboxSelector).change(setActiveLinks);
   
   // call it on load
   setActiveLinks();
});

function setActiveLinks() {
   var radioValue = $(radioSelector +':checked').val();
   var isChecked = $(checkboxSelector).prop("checked");

   // first dis-active links
   $('.my-toggle-links > button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('hidden d-none');

   // second active
   var activeSelector = '.my-toggle-links[data-radio="'+ radioValue +'"][data-checked="'+ isChecked +'"]';
   $(activeSelector + ', ' + activeSelector +' > button').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hidden d-none');
}
```

```css
.hidden, .d-none { display: none; }
```

```html
<!-- Radio buttons_Button 2 selected by default -->
<div>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> Radio 1</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" checked> Radio 2</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3"> Radio 3</label><br> 
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">
 <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio2 & Unchecked by default -->
<div>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="false"><button>URL1 Radio1 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url2' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="false"><button>URL2 Radio2 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url3' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="false"><button>URL3 Radio3 & Unchecked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url4' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"><button>URL4 Radio1 & Checked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url5' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="true"><button>URL5 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/url6' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="true"><button>URL6 Radio2 & Checked</button></a>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: OMG!! I'm pleasantly shocked that you took your precious time & energy to answer my question! This is my 1st question ever here, and I was afraid that I will just be ignored. I'm going to check out the code now. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Is it possible to have just 1 button and with its URL selected based on the combination of radio button & checkbox?

<div>
 <button>Button</button>
</div>

URLs
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url1 for Radio 1 & unchecked
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url2 for Radio 2 & unchecked (default)
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url3 for Radio 3 & unchecked
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url4 for Radio 1 & checked
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url5 for Radio 2 & checked
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/url6 for Radio 3 & checked

Comment: Wow!! Thank you again for your kind support!! I'm grateful that you have solved this riddle. I just couldn't bridge the gap between courses & texts to real-life coding. I clicked on the checkmark, so that should take care of the best answer thingie. :) I'm so glad I took the dive to ask my question here after much hesitation.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to achieve the desired result is:

1. Put all radio buttons in one radio button group
2. Put the two checkboxes is one checkbox group.
3. Get the part-1 of the url string from radio button selected.
4. Get part-2 of the url string from the checkboxes selected.
5. Required URL will be the concatenation of part-1 and part-2

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate your feedback!